# Как портировать UEFI на свой телефон (где найти необходимую информацию)?

Tags: android, uefi, порт

Скажем так, я даже не прошу, чтобы за меня сделали или 'от и до' озвучили порядок действий. Я просто хочу понять, где мне искать нужную информацию, получить какие-то рекомендации, что и как делать.

Так вот, я намерен портировать на свой телефон UEFI - будь то уже устаревший EFIDroid, а лучше Tianocore, как на SDM845 (мой девайс на SDM660). Конкретно на мой девайс нету EDK. Видел на Pixel 3 и Xiaomi lavender порты EDK2. Но я хочу собрать, с нуля, на свое устройство, по понятным причинам. Однако EFIDroid устарел, а я не нашёл внятного ответа, что делать. Смотрел исходники EDK2: казалось бы, достаточно выдернуть dtb (через magiskboot легко это сделать), xbl.img (`/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/xbl`), и дело за малым. Но я вообще понятия не имею о самом процессе сборки и работы EDK-II, да на ряде девайсов этот EDK все равно крайне нестабильно работает. Так что мне лучше пройти тернистый путь `сборки из исходников по гайдам от умельцев или самой Tianocore`.

Answer (score 1):

Увы, чтобы портировать UEFI на свой девайс, недостаточно просто выдрать XBL и DTB из памяти устройства, а информации на эту тему действительно довольно мало... Я в попытках портировать UEFI EDK2 на SDM665 (уже как полгода)

Следует проделать действительно сложную работу, вот несколько ключевых шагов на ранних этапах:

1. Начать нужно с выбора исходного кода какого-либо другого устройства (например lavender), который вы измените под ваши нужды
2. Далее следует вытащить XBL из устройства и разобрать его на DXE модули и засунуть в папку Binary в вашем исходном коде
3. Выдёргиваем DTB из устройства и помещаем в наш исходный код
4. Пытаемся собрать... Начинается небольшая борьба с починкой старых зависимостей (решаются легко если уметь гуглить)
5. Если у нас всё собралось, то конечно ничего работать не будет (стоит привыкнуть, ибо на ранних этапах может быть так, что вы будете словно искать ошибку в стоге сена, так как у вас не будет даже вывода лога (я боролся с тенью около месяца, после у меня появилась отладка через framebuffer))
6. Начался этап редактирования кода. Следует правильно выбрать обьём памяти, который будет использовать EDK 2 для своих нужд (файл .dsc, строчка gArmTokenSpaceGuid.PcdSystemMemorySize)
7. Из XBL стоит также извлечь uefiplat.cfg и по нему редактировать файл DeviceMemoryMap.h

Это довольно поверхностно, дальше вам нужно будет самим "сделать исследовательскую работу" (углубиться в историю портов UEFI EDK2 на разные устройства Pixel 3 XL и его форки), так же стоит заглянуть в официальную документацию EDK2 и изучить основные концепции, методы отладки и т.д., могу ещё сказать, что на устройствах, имеющих XBL, из коробки работает UEFI, но он специально сконфигурирован под функции загрузки Android, а так же работы протоколов типа Fastboot и другие.

Извините, если отбил желание занимать этим действительно интересным делом, но вам стоит знать то, с чем вам предстоит столкнуться. Желаю удачи!

Comment: неплохо, а как распаковать xbl.img?

Comment: Можно с помощью UEFITool или скрипта в репозитории lavender, но на сколько я помню, он работает только с XBL.elf

Comment: xbl.elf... а как мне найти правильно ELF, на что ориентироваться?

Comment: у каждого устройства по-разному, у кого-то .img у кого-то .elf, UEFITool распакует и то и другое https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool

Comment: я не нашёл ничего в исходниках edk2-lavender. Скачал UEFITool, uefi-firmware-parser, вытащил через binwalk xbl.uefi, разобрал..

Comment: Тот скрипт довольно заморочный и его надо править, иначе - ошибка, так что не используйте его

Comment: у меня, что интересно, UEFI нашёлся ещё и в ABOOT... разобрал через UEFITool aboot.img (даже не elf)

Comment: ABL и XBL - неразлучные компоненты UEFI, в xbl располагаются проприентарные DXE модули, а в abl находится сам EDK2

Comment: не знаю, как там должно быть, но ни UEFITool, ни uefi-firmware-parser, не находили ничего Dxe-шного. Нашло только .pe файл в aboot и .te (terse executable) + ffs в xbl